# Converting date and time from Excel to R with input '2016-09-25 17:13:46.030'

Tags: r, datetime, import-from-excel

I have been trying to use the as.PosIXct() to import a combined date & time variable from Excel to R. The format that I want to import looks like this: '2016-09-25 17:13:46.030'. I want it to look like this in R: '2016-09-25 17:13:46'. When I use the code below, I get back only NA values.

```
 fd$AnswerValue <- as.POSIXct(as.character(fd$AnswerValue), 
                format = '%y%m%d%H%M', origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
```

I expect this has something to do with the three additional decimals of the second counts in the original file. Anyone with advice?

Comment: Try capital `%Y` in the format as it is 4 digits.

Comment: If only it were that simple :). Didn't work unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `lubridate` solution would be:

```
test <- "2016-09-25 17:13:46.030"

library(lubridate)

ymd_hms(test)
```

Or the base function, but longer:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(test), 
       format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
```

Comment: The lubridate function works like a charm. Thank you J_F